# Why is the client not connecting to my tcp server?

Tags: windows, rust, server, tcp, port

I'm unable to connect to my server with the client eventhough. My laptop acts as the client and my PC acts as the server, they are connected to the same wifi. I tried turning the windows firewall off but it didn't help. This is the error code my laptop (client) is getting: `Error: Os { code: 10061, kind: ConnectionRefused, message: "No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it." }`

Client code that runs on the laptop:

```
use std::io::prelude::*;
use std::net::TcpStream;

fn main() -> std::io::Result<()> {
    let mut stream = TcpStream::connect("localhost:8080")?;

    stream.write(&[1])?;
    stream.read(&mut [0; 128])?;
    Ok(())
} // the stream is closed here
```

Server code that runs on the PC:

```
use std::net::{TcpListener, TcpStream};
use std::io::{Read, Write};
use std::io::{BufReader,BufWriter};

fn handle_client(stream: TcpStream) {
    // ...
    let mut reader = BufReader::new(&stream);
    let mut response = String::new();
    reader.read_to_string(&mut response).unwrap();
    println!("{}", response);
}

fn main() -> std::io::Result<()> {
    let listener = TcpListener::bind("0.0.0.0:8080")?;

    // accept connections and process them serially
    for stream in listener.incoming() {
        handle_client(stream?);
    }
    Ok(())
}
```

Comment: I pretty sure localhost is not the address of your OTHER machine, thus the name LOCAL host.

Comment: Is that the problem? @Stargateur

Comment: you are machine A, you try to contact machine B, but use locahost of machine A, you need ip of machine B

Comment: Alright, how can I ger the ip of the server? @Stargateur

Comment: May I suggest ensuring you can create a TCP connection using an easier, tried-and-true tool like `nc` (netcat) before diving straight into custom Rust code? That way you would know the issue is in your code and not the connection itself (which I suspect is the case here).

Comment: easy way:  on the server (PC) - open cmd and call ipconfig, then try all the available onces. you can try them with ping from the laptop first. you could probably also write code that gives the IP address of the server: see this [thread](https://users.rust-lang.org/t/best-way-to-get-your-own-ips/14308/3)

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify hostname or IP of the other machine instead of `localhost`. You can find it by hand and hardcode it. If you want your program to find the other machine on your local network automatically, that's [a complex annoying problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero-configuration_networking) which itself is way bigger than what you're trying to do here.

After you connect both machines, you'll find that your programs gets stuck.

That's because `read_to_string` never stops reading until the connection is entirely closed. TCP is not message-based, so the other side will not read a single `write`, it will keep reading and waiting until the other side hangs up. You will need to devise a protocol that knows exactly how many bytes it needs to read, before reading them, and won't ask for a byte more (e.g. send length of a string before the string).